# Image not Recognized by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, animation

**HTML Code**

```
<div>
    <img  id="in" width="300px">
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
    var image = document.getElementById("in");
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png";
image.animate({marginTop: "100vh"});
```

Everytime I run this program, I am able to load the image, but I am unable to perform the animation on it. I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

What should I do to fix this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ay2faLs/1/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image` is a dom element not jQuery so there is no method called animate in it

```
var image = document.getElementById("in");
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png";
$(image).animate({
    marginTop: "100vh"
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gb0sms77/)

---

You can also use jQuery selectors to access the img element at set the src like

```
$('#in').attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png').animate({
    marginTop: "100vh"
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gb0sms77/2/)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

jQuery functions can only be executed off jQuery selected elements, use

```
var image = $("#in");
```

Another way is that, you are making a *native element* instead of a *jQuery* element. This means it won't have access to a jQuery function

### Why and How

The way jQuery is coded, is that functions such as `.animate()` are a `prototype` *([info](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/))*

### More

You can also use jQuery [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to shorten your code. jQuery functions can be *chained*, or put together.

```
$("#in").attr({
    'src': "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png"
}).animate({
    marginTop: "100vh"
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/945a0cv9/)